# Issues while creating rundeck windows node and using key authentication process

Tags: rundeck

I have followed http://www.techpaste.com/2015/08/rundeck-windows-nodes-configuration/ and created windows node but while I am running a job its saying "Password is not set" but when I am providing password as an option named winrmPassword then its working.
I have written :

name="win_node" connectionType="WINRM_NATIVE" node-executor="overthere-winrm" winrm-password-option="winrmPassword"
winrm-protocol="http" winrm-auth-type="basic" username="winrmuser"
hostname="ec2-54-213-198-191.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com"

and giving  winrmPassword as option. It is working.
So 
1. how do I run a job in multiple node if each password is different?
2. How can I use keys for windows authentication? Can anyone share resource.xml file for the same?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the above issue:
1. We must use key based auth if we want to run same cmd in multiple windows nodes at a time.
2. For key based auth in windows ;
  i. At first follow all steps from  http://www.techpaste.com/2015/08/rundeck-windows-nodes-configuration/ and configure openSSH asd winrm for all windows nodes. Make sure firewall rules are properly set for winrm in windows node.
 ii. Follow http://www.techpaste.com/2015/06/windows-ssh-server-setup-and-configuration/ and make sure we can run commands to target windows node from rundeck server without giving password, only though keys. Give permission to read the private key you can give permission using chmod command.
 iii. update resources.xml file :

```
<node name="node_name"  username="winrmuser"
  hostname="hostname_for_windows_node" ssh-keypath="full_path_to_private_key"
    ssh-authentication="privateKey"
    ssh-key-passphrase-option="option.sshKeyPassphrase"/>
```

You are done!! You can run any commands through rundeck to target node as winrmuser has admin access.